# How to generate more than one reports in crystal reports horizontally in-addition to vertically?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have made a program in c# that generates ID cards, with records stored in access. Now, the dimensions of the ID card are such that two or maybe three ID cards can fit horizontally on a page. Crystal reports generates the second ID card vertically below the first one. Is there any way I could make it generate horizontally as well to save paper ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for the details section to format with multiple columns . Right click on details and select Section Expert, then check the checkbox "Format with Multiple columns" ( on right)